# RCov started analyzing loaded libs (including Rdoc itself) – when using rvm (Ruby Version Manager)

Tags: ruby, rvm, rcov

## Context

- rcov 0.9.8 2010-02-28
- ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.3.0]
- rvm 0.1.38 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
- System Ruby (rvm use system): ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10]

## Files

The test setup is a 'lib' folder containing a single file which defines a class, the folders 'test' and 'test/sub_test', with 'sub_test' containing the single 'test_example_lib.rb' and a Rakefile like this:

```
require 'rcov/rcovtask'

task :default => [:rcov]

desc "RCov"
Rcov::RcovTask.new do | t |
    t.test_files = FileList[ 'test/**/test_*.rb' ]
end
```

## Result

```
#rake
(in /Users/stephan/tmp/rcov_example)
rm -r coverage
Loaded suite /Users/stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin/rcov
Started
.
Finished in 0.000508 seconds.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|                  File                              | Lines |  LOC  |  COV   |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|...ms/rcov-0.9.8/lib/rcov/code_coverage_analyzer.rb |   271 |   156 |   5.1% |
|...ems/rcov-0.9.8/lib/rcov/differential_analyzer.rb |   116 |    82 |   9.8% |
|lib/example_lib.rb                                  |    16 |    11 |  72.7% |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|Total                                               |   403 |   249 |   9.6% |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+
9.6%   3 file(s)   403 Lines   249 LOC
```

## Question

Why is RCov itself analysed here? 
I'd expect that (and it doesn't happen when using 'rvm use system').
In fact it seems to be due to me using a Ruby installed via rvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some exclusion in rcov :

--exclude /gems/,/Library/,/usr/,spec,lib/tasks

```
require 'rcov/rcovtask'

task :default => [:rcov]

desc "RCov"
Rcov::RcovTask.new do | t |
    t.test_files = FileList[ 'test/**/test_*.rb' ]
    t.rcov_opts << '--exclude /gems/,/Library/,/usr/,spec,lib/tasks'
end
```